# Create Button with event handler on button click without putting it on page_load event in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch some student entries based on some selected search options and want to associate edit and delete buttons with it.

[Search Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waDOv.png)

In above image. By clicking Search button. I am generating List of student and associated Edit and Delete Buttons. But it is not invoking the event handler.
[list With Buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbAaY.png)

.aspx code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="search_text"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="search_text_Click" ValidationGroup="submit">Search  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
<div class="row" runat="server">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ShowContentPanel" HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

.aspx.cs Code:
**Event called on Search Button Click.**

```
protected void search_text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    **Fetching the values**

    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.Text = "Edit";
    button1.ID = "Edit_" + id1 + "_" + id2;
    button1.CssClass = "btn btn-info btn-md";
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(Edit_Click);
    ShowContentPanel.Controls.Add(button1);

    Label space = new Label();
    space.Text = "&nbsp;";
    ShowContentPanel.Controls.Add(space);

    Button button2 = new Button();
    button2.Text = "Delete";
    button2.ID = "Del_" + id1 + "_" + id2;
    button2.CssClass = "btn btn-warning";
    button2.Click += new EventHandler(Delete_Click);
    ShowContentPanel.Controls.Add(button2);           
}
```

For those buttons we have two event handlers

```
private void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: If you do not recreate those buttons on PostBack their event will not trigger.

Comment: i am creating those buttons using the button click. so these are created on the post back. than also it is not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.NET is finished rendering the page, the entire page object is destroyed, along with any buttons that had been created-- including the dynamic buttons you are adding via code.

When the user clicks the Edit button, the page posts back yet again, and the Edit button is nowhere to be found. Why? Since the button is not added in `page_load`, it is only created for the round trip when the user clicked `search_text`. So the button is gone, and its event won't fire.

In situations like this, it is better to add the control in the page_load event (the normal way). If you only want the Edit button to appear when the user clicks some text, set its Visible property to false by default and simply set it to true when the user clicks the text. That way the button always exists and you won't have to worry about creating it just to handle an event. Or better yet, just hide it with CSS, and unhide it with Javascript-- that will save the user from having to make a round trip to the server just to show a button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the point. But I doesn't know that how many buttons i need. It depends on the retrieved values. So, How can i create the button and set the property true and false.

Comment: you can see the second Image of my Question "List with Buttons". Which can give you the complete idea about my problem.